# CLion "if" live template brace for C programming

Tags: clion, jetbrains-ide

I am trying to make "if" template to look like this:

[image]

but when I enter it in actual code, it comes out as:

[image]

I want upper brace to be 1 line below but it comes on the same line. Is there anything wrong in my template?

Comment: Seems like your global style settings puts your opening brace on the same line. Try to search action (Ctrl + Shift + A) by name "Braces placement" or open Settings > Editor > Code Style > Wrapping and Braces > Braces placement

Comment: Or if you do not want to change global settings, you may disable "Reformat according to style" (right bottom corner)

Comment: thank you so much. This worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like your global style settings puts your opening brace on the same line. Try to search action (Ctrl + Shift + A) by name "Braces placement":

[image]

Or open Settings > Editor > Code Style > Wrapping and Braces > Braces placement

[image]

Or just disable "Reformat according to style":

[image]

Comment: +1 for the details and screenshots. But, please, don't disable the reformatting. Train it to do your bidding. It's such a useful feature that having to apply a tweak here and there is well worth the time and effort.

Comment: That is why I put it on the bottom of the post